# jQuery: combining after and html methods

Tags: jquery

As you know in jQuery we can combine methods. But here I have a problem.

```js
$('div').after('<span class="text-warning" >SPAN</span>').html('test');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>DIV</div>
```

.html inserts the text in div. Shouldn't it change new element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, 'after' is an operator and will return whatever it operated on. In this case, the div.

What you want is something like:

```
var span = $('<span class="text-warning" >SPAN</span>')
$('div').after(span)
span.html('test');
```

Answer (score 2):

this is a technique called chaining , that allows us to run multiple jQuery commands, one after the other, on the same element(s).

To chain an action, you simply append the action to the previous action.

In case you :

```
$('div').after('<span class="text-warning" >SPAN</span>')
        .html('test');
```

in step 1 ,insert `span` tag after `div` tag

And

in step 2 , text in `div` change to "test".

You can fix like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('div').after('<span class="text-warning">SPAN</span>');

    $(".text-warning").html('test');

})
```